# Left-align headers in Markdown table?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Using the table example from "[Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)" on GitHub, you get this:

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```

[image]

My question is, is there any way to left-align the header cells while retaining the alignment in the image? IE, I want to align the header *differently* than the body.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It depends on which implementation you are using.

Tables are a non-standard feature of Markdown and each implementation which supports them does so differently. For example, the "cheetsheet" pointed to in the question is within the [Markdown Here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here) project. That project's Readme includes the following explanation:

> To discover what can be done with Markdown in Markdown Here, check out the [Markdown Here Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Here-Cheatsheet) and the other [wiki pages](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki).

So that "cheetsheet" is specific to the implementation used by Markdown Here.

GitHub has [documented](https://github.github.com/gfm/) their implementation of Markdown as an [extension](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-) of the Commonmark spec ([Commonmark](http://commonmark.org) is a Markdown variant which does not support tables). According to [example 192](https://github.github.com/gfm/#example-192), the column headers receive the same alignment as the column cells:

> ```
> | abc | defghi |
> :-: | -----------:
> bar | baz
>
> <table>
> <thead>
> <tr>
> <th align="center">abc</th>
> <th align="right">defghi</th>
> </tr>
> </thead>
> <tbody>
> <tr>
> <td align="center">bar</td>
> <td align="right">baz</td>
> </tr></tbody></table>
> ```

So, you need to check the specific implementation of Markdown you are using and read that implementation's documentation. However, personally, I have never come across an implementation which allows you to define separate alignment for the headers from the cells. In my experience, either you get headers which match the cells, or headers which have no alignment assigned.

Answer (score 39):

---

Markdown:

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
|:------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| col 1 is      | left-aligned  |   $42 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```

---

Result:

| Tables | Are | Cool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col 3 is | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is | centered | $12 |
| col 1 is | left-aligned | $42 |
| zebra stripes | are neat | $1 |

---

Note that the colon (":") on the second row, and the second character is what worked to
The other option is to move the numbers to the left-most column (as below)

```
Amount | Items
------:|:-----
    20 | Wooden Boards
     5 | Old Parts
```

Try it on [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).

It does not seem to work putting the ---- line above the headers.

Comment: The header cells in your result image are not left aligned.  Did SO change something or was your answer always incorrect?

Comment: this changes the alignment for the entire column, the question was to just change the alignment of the table headers only

Answer (score 10):

On the second line, I would change to this to align everything (headers and content) to the left:

```
| :------------ | :-------------- | :----- |
```

Notice the colons on the left of each column.

Comment: Yes, this left aligns everything, which is not what I want.

Comment: To align (e.g. center) an individual cell, you can use `<center>Some cell content</center>`.

Comment: @PetrVepřek GitHub ignores `<center>` in table cells, same with `<div style="text-align: center;">`..